# Convert a time range into a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, range

I have the following pandas dataframe that shows a range for each event:

```
df
Event   Start   End
1       4       6
1       30      32
1       41      43
```

I am trying to extend these ranges by 1 (including the upper bound) for each event and append them all into a list. For example, for event 1, I am looking to get something like this:
[4, 5, 6, 30, 31, 32, 41, 42, 43]
I have this function currently and it seems working fine, however, I am wondering if there is a smarter/cleaner way to do this in python.

```
def time_ranges(start,end):       
       tmp_range=[]
       for s, e in zip(start,end):
          tmp_range.append([s, e])
        
       time_range = []
       for i in tmp_range:
           time_range.extend((range(int(i[0]), int(i[1])+1, 1)))
       return time_range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
def time_ranges(start,end):      
    return [i for s, e in zip(start,end) for i in list(range(s, e+1))]
print(time_ranges([4,30,41], [6,32,43]))
```

```
[4, 5, 6, 30, 31, 32, 41, 42, 43]
```

or if you dont want a flat list:

```
def time_ranges(start,end):       
    return [list(range(s, e+1)) for s, e in zip(start,end)]
print(time_ranges([4,30,41], [6,32,43]))
```

```
[[4, 5, 6], [30, 31, 32], [41, 42, 43]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
df.groupby('Event')\
  .apply(lambda x: [q for i, j in zip(x['Start'], x['End']) for q in np.arange(i, j+1)])
```

Output:

```
Event
1    [4, 5, 6, 30, 31, 32, 41, 42, 43]
dtype: object
```